# df.corr() command in python

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation

I want to find the correlation between the columns of a dataframe in python. I would like to ask which correlation coefficient provides df.corr(). Correlation R or something else?

For example, df.corr(method='spearman', min_periods=1) computes spearman rank correlation, and my question is when the parenthesis is empty what python computes ?

Thanks,
Dimitris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it is `DataFrame.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html))

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I thought that DataFrame.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1) in the top of the link was a random example , and not the default parameters by default.

Comment: In documentation, this should be the default parameters, if there are examples, they should be below.

Comment: Perfectly, thank you , you are right the result is exactly the same.